# Can't find React Native app deployed on Play Store with Expo

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo, google-play-console

4 days ago, I created an internal test release of a mobile application developed with React Native and Expo. I used Expo to generate the apk file.
Everything seems good on **Google Play Console**.

[image: 1]

And I didn't forget to add a tester (myself) with my mail address. So, I've access to **the link to provide to testers**
[image: 2].

But when I click on the given link to download my app as tester on my browser it displays **this message**[image: 3] and when I follow the link with my Android device there's an infinite loading on Play Store.

I didn't forget to enable developer options in Play Store and the possibility to share internal applications.

Thanks.